# Hacer xhrFields: { withCredentials: true } de AJAX en CURL PHP

Tags: php, curl

En la petición `POST` en `AJAX` tengo esto para conservar la sesión de usuario de la web externa.

```
xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
crossDomain: true
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto mismo en `CURL` en `PHP`?

Answer (score 0):

Por supuesto 
       CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = 0;
       CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST = 2;

estas variables debes configurar